# No HTML on InfoWindow when using setContent

Tags: javascript, python, html, google-maps, flask

I have been using the Flask-GoogleMaps extension from:
https://github.com/nikulesko/Flask-GoogleMaps

I am trying to insert some HTML in my InfoWindows however these do not show up (the tags themselves show up as plaintext). How would I achieve this? I thought that passing the string with HTML tags on it would render the HTML on the infoWindow however this does not work. This is how the content of infoWindow is set:

```
        var infoWindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "loading..."
        });

         {% for marker in gmap.markers %}
             var marker_{{loop.counter}} = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: new google.maps.LatLng({{marker.0}}, {{marker.1}}),
                 map: {{gmap.varname}},
                 title: '{{marker.2}}',
                 icon: '{{marker.3}}',
             });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker_{{loop.counter}}, 'click', function() {
                 infoWindow.setContent('{{marker.4}}');
                 infoWindow.open({{gmap.varname}}, this);
             });
         {% endfor %}
```

Any ideas? `markers` is a list containing tuples of a `marker` which has a `(latitude, longitude, title, icon, info)`. so `marker.4` is a string.

EDIT: I have tried to do something like

```
infoWindow.setContent("some text with html...")
```

and this works fine showing the HTML but when I do

```
infoWindow.setContent("{{marker.4}}")
```

the HTML does not show up. I have also tried setting a variable (just before the line where addListener is called):

```
var contentStr = '{{marker.4}}';
```

then:

```
infoWindow.setContent(contentStr);
```

however, this doesnt work either. I dont understand what the difference between passing jinja variables and plain js. How would I achieve the functionality I want using a python string/jinja variable?

Comment: I thought it would be something like that, so I changed it to double quotes, but I still get the problem. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

In **jinja2**, inside a [`for` loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for) you don't have `loop.counter` but `loop.index` which shows you the current iteration of the loop (starting from 1). And `loop.index0` which does the some thing starting from 0.

Also you should put between quotes all jinja variables in your javascript code, for ex:

```
position: new google.maps.LatLng("{{marker.0}}", "{{marker.1}}")
```

Comment: I found the solution to this problem...it seems it has nothing to do with either of those but I needed to put "|safe" for anything that has html on it. So "{{marker.4}}" becomes "{{marker.4|safe}}"

Comment: @user1397215 which version of flask do you use?